# get count of users in a voice channel? Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

How can I get the count of users in a voice channel?
I have a system that counts the time of users in the voice channel, I want it to work if there are more than two people in the voice channel, please tell me.
Code:

```
exports.execute = async (oldState, newState) => {
    if ((oldState.member && oldState.member.user.bot) || (newState.member && newState.member.user.bot)) {
        return;
    }

    if (!oldState.channelID && newState.channelID) {
        Activites.set(oldState.id, Date.now());
    }

    let data;

    if (!Activites.has(oldState.id)) {
        data = Date.now();
        Activites.set(oldState.id, data);
    }
    else {
        data = Activites.get(oldState.id);
    }

    let duration = Date.now() - data;

    if (oldState.channelID && !newState.channelID) {
        Activites.delete(oldState.id);
        vt.add(`stats.${oldState.guild.id}.${oldState.id}.channels.${oldState.channelID}`, duration);
        vt.set(`stats.${oldState.guild.id}.${oldState.id}.activity`, Date.now());
    }
    else if (oldState.channelID && newState.channelID) {
        Activites.set(oldState.id, Date.now());
        vt.add(`stats.${oldState.guild.id}.${oldState.id}.channels.${oldState.channelID}`, duration);
        vt.set(`stats.${oldState.guild.id}.${oldState.id}.activity`, Date.now());
    }
};
```

Comment: to do that you need to get the voicechannel of your choice and then you can count the members in there. See [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceChannel) for the docs.

Answer (score 0):

First, you get the channel you want, then you can get the size of the `members` property of it.

```js
let voiceChannel = client.guilds.cache.get("guild id").channels.cache.get("channel id");
let membersInChannel = voiceChannel.members.size;
```

Comment: If I want to track this in all channels at once, where does the user go?

Comment: I'm confused by what you mean by `user`?

Comment: I mean oldState.id, that is, so that the system does not check the channel I specified, but the channel where the user enters.
example,
 `let voiceChannel = newState.channelID;
 let membersInChannel = voiceChannel.members.size; 
 if(membersInChannel == 1){
  return;
 }
 
 if (oldState.channelID || oldState.ChannelID && !newState.channelID || newState.ChannelID) {
***code***
}`